# Calling PHP script with ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Right now I have this:

```
echo "<a href='misc/removeWallComment.php?id=" . 
    $displayWall['id'] . "&uID" . $displayWall['uID'] . "&BuID" . 
    $displayWall['BuID'] . "' title='ta bort inlägg'> 
    <span class='removeWallComment'></span> </a>";
```

Its an icon with a link that removes the comment when you click.

Now, it goes to `misc/removeWallComment.php` and echo out "comment removed". But I would like to integrate it with my current site, so you don't go to another page to delete the commehnt. With this I thought of using an ajax call to `removeWallComment.php`.

Now as you see on the link it requires three variables, `id`, `uID` and `BuID`, and I want to send it `POST`, not `GET` so the user can't see the variables in address bar. On success it should just alert ok.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that this question will have an answer:

```
var links = $('.removeWallComment').parent();

links.click(function(event) {
    // Parse out the ids
    var data = this.href.substring('?').split('&');

    var id = data[0].substring(data[0].indexOf('=') + 1);
    var uid = data[1].substring(data[1].indexOf('=') + 1);
    var BuID = data[2].substring(data[2].indexOf('=') + 1);

    $.post('misc/removeWallComment.php', {
        'id': id,
        'uid': uid,
        'BuID': BuID
    }, function(data){
        // Success!
        alert('OK');
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

It doesn't matter if you use `GET` or `POST`, if you're using ajax you're user will never see the three `id`s in the address bar. The three `id`s, however, must be gotten somehow, so in this case we are parsing the `href` value for them (the three `id` **must** be stored somewhere, preferably on the element itself for easy retrieval. If you want to hide the `id`s for security reasons this isn't the best way to do it).